# Carl Anderson's discovery of positron

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, electrons, history, antimatter

The picture below is a photograph taken by Carl Anderson in 1932.
It shows for the first time the existence of an anti-electron.
https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/200408/history.cfm
[image]

The article goes on to state: "Despite initial skepticism from the scientific community, Anderson's result was confirmed the following year, and scientists concluded that the positron was one of a pair of positive and negative electrons produced when a gamma ray converted into matter."

My question is: Why is there no track showing the path of the electron?

Comment: What electron? Note the picture heading: *"Anderson's cloud chamber picture of cosmic radiation from 1932 [...]"*, the positron is coming from space here, it's not produced inside the picture.

Comment: Because this is a positron track, entering from the bottom of the photo at an estimated 63MeV, losing energy passing through the lead plate (horizontal), and exiting at an estimated 23MeV. The curvature makes it a positive charge.

Comment: To be fair, the original article is much clearer than the APS blurb, so it is worth checking out (available free).

Comment: @JonCuster even the abstract is clear https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.43.491

Comment: @annav - I agree. Kind of disappointing that the APS could make it as unclear as it did...

Comment: @ACuriousMind The article states that this positron is produced by a Pair Production process

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JonCuster. I am not sure how to upvote your comment.

Comment: It states the general statement that seeing a positron implies it was produced in the cosmic radiation by the energy of a gamma going into a pair e+ e- . related  my answer to question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95918/why-does-the-spiral-of-a-positron-have-a-larger-radius-than-that-of-an-electron