# Can the probability of finding a particle in a certain finite region be zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, scattering, probability, double-slit-experiment

Don't worry this time isn't about doubleslit but I'll still use it for my question.
Imagine an electron is emitted from the source and I shall allow a certain amount of time to lapsed so as to provide sufficient time for that electron to cross the slit, now is the probability of finding the electron in-between the source and the slit zero or non-zero? Intuition says it's zero because electron should already made it's way across the slits unimpeded by this time but my gut's feeling told me it's a wave function so chances are it's probably still there.

Comment: This simulation might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-YDj2odL8I&ab_channel=NilsBerglund

Comment: in quantum mechanics probabilities can be measured in an ensemble of particles with the same boundary conditions, not for single electrons as you seem to imply.

Comment: Look at the image of  particles  detected in a bubble chamber https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95918/why-does-the-spiral-of-a-positron-have-a-larger-radius-than-that-of-an-electron . The paths are continuous interactions of the particles with the medium, the width reflects the probability of interactions, i.e. the wavefunction for each individual dot. The particles have a fixed path in space within that . This means the probability of their being a centimeter away is  zero.